# What do French tennis announcers say when the game is tied at 15 or 30 ?

Tags: oral, argot, sport

When a game is tied at 15 or 30 the French tennis announcers say something that sounds to me like "quinze un " (resp. "trente un") or maybe "quinze an" .  "Quinze" is only said once, no "quinze quinze" or "quinze partout'.  My best guess is that the final vowel is emphasized and they are saying 'quinz-E' ?  Does someone know ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I first believed it was *trente à*, and short for *trente à trente*. But it's actually written *trente-A* in [official tennis procedures](http://www.itftennis.com/media/167430/167430.pdf) :

> Le score
>
> 1. On annonce toujours les points du serveur en premier, sauf pour le jeu décisif.
> 2. On annonce le score comme suit :
>    « *Quinze-zéro, zéro-quinze, trente-zéro, zéro-trente, quarante-zéro, zéro-
>    quarante, quinze-A, quinze-trente, trente-quinze, quinze-quarante,
>    quarante-quinze, trente-A, quarante-trente, trente-quarante, (la 1<sup>ère</sup> fois),
>    égalité (jamais quarante-A), avantage, jeu.* »
> 3. Si l’on utilise le système de décompte des points du No-Ad (sans avantage)
>    on annonce après « égalité » : *Point décisif, choix du relanceur*.
> 4. On annoncera le score d’une voix forte et distincte à la fin d’un point. On
>    tâchera de faire l’annonce avant les applaudissements et avant de porter le
>    score sur la feuille d’arbitrage, sauf dans une situation où une annonce
>    différée produirait plus d’effet.
>    […]

It might come from the English “thirty all”.

Tennis scoring is [very peculiar](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis#Origine_historique_de_la_marque_des_points).

Note however that in the Montreal half of the Rogers Cup the umpires say *quinze partout* and *trente partout*, which is also an accepted way of expressing tie scores in other sports including table tennis.